# Need Idea for implementing jdbc table of MS Access in Java Frame

Tags: java, jdbc, jframe, crud

I am working on an project where an admin has to view, edit or delete the entries in the database i.e. MS Access which is connected by JDBC in Java frame. Can you help me click an idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- Create database
- Fill entries in it
- Make an admin user
- Make java program to do the CRUD operations

To display data you can use [JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) in JFrame.

Tutorial:- [CreatingaJTable](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingaJTable.htm)

Comment: I've done the above steps. I just need a better way to display that database in admin side frame where i can edit and delete the same. Just same as we have an option for gridview in asp.net. Thanks for ur support.

Comment: Yes this seems a good idea. Can I include the logic of updating and deleting in that JTable itself?